# Connected CPU to PCI-E connector. Did I fry something?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, amd-ryzen

I just bought an AMD motherboard and CPU and a modular PSU.

The PSU came with a cable with 2 8-PIN connectors, one RED and one BLACK.

I haven't been  careful enough and I connected the motherboard's 12v 8-PIN CPU connector (BLACK) using the BLACK-RED cable to the RED connector on the PSU.

The computer did not start and the PSU was making a lot of hissing noise. Even the CPU fan was not running. I disconnected everything.

Subsequently, I re-checked the connections and realised I connected the 12V 8-PIN CPU connector to the PCI-E connector of the PSU.

I amended the connection and when I press the power button the fan now spins up but the computer still doesn't start.

Did I fry something? What may I have fried?

Comment: "Did I fry something?" - It's very likely.  "What may I have fried?" - The entire motherboard and anything directed to the PCIe VCC bus.  With as many layers as the motherboard has there is no repairing that kind of damage (if it exists).

Comment: What's connected to the PCIe VCC bus?

Comment: I checked the pinouts and, apparently, I shorted the +12VCC from the PSU to the GND of the motherboard. The +12VCC of the CPU on the other hand was on GND so that didn't receive any power and should be good. As those are power connectors, not signal connectors, I just might get lucky. The fact that lights on the motherboards turn on and that it responds to the power button gives me hope that it's a DoA on the CPU side. I'll try replacing components one by one until I find what happened and post the solution.

If anyone ever experienced this problem, please let me know how it played out.

Comment: You shorted 12 Volts to ground, that’s how you fry components completely, like magic smoke fry

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends. Eventually I decided to get a new motherboard and processor regardless. Received the new ones, they didn't power up with a behaviour entirely similar to that of the previous motherboard after I amended the problem. Eventually, they were turning up inconsistently. I believe it's a PSU problem at this point as shorting that one can definitely blow some of its components. As to whether mobo and cpu got fried, it will remain a mystery. RAM and SSD didn't suffer any consequence.